# How to find out the IP address who performed DML operations on a certain table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Is there a way to find out the IP address who performed DML operations on a certain table in Oracle?

If ip is not possible, then how to find the SID?

Thanks.

Comment: IP address and SID are mentioned in the tnsnames.ora file

Comment: You can make an [Audit Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#BABCFIHB). The audit contains also SID and host

Comment: @Wernfried Is there any other way to do without Audit Trail? Because it is not enabled ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need however.

If you want to know what is your SID `SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;`

However IF you want to know who made DML operations on tables, then check [Streams, replication of a DML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14228/gen_rep.htm#i1007907)

> A capture process or an application creates one or more logical change
>   records (LCRs) and enqueues them into a queue. An LCR is a message
>   with a specific format that describes a database change. A capture
>   process reformats changes captured from the redo log into LCRs, and
>   applications can construct LCRs. If the change was a data manipulation
>   language (DML) operation, then each LCR encapsulates a row change
>   resulting from the DML operation to a shared table at the source
>   database. If the change was a data definition language (DDL)
>   operation, then an LCR encapsulates the DDL change that was made to a
>   shared database object at a source database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AUDIT_TABLE (USER_NAME VARCHAR2(30), IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(15), SID NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUDIT_DML_CERTAIN_TABLE
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON CERTAIN_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE 
    VALUES (USER, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID'));
END;
```

But be aware, it is quite easy to bypass or counterfeit this kind of logging if someone has bad intention. The more secure way is to enable the audit trail.